# Computing a text document of numbers. Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to calculate the sum and average of a text document filled with 10000 numbers.¨
This is my code:

```
with open("\\Users\\saksa\\python_courses\\1DV501\\assign3\\file_10000integers_A.txt", "r") as f:
total = 0
number_of_ints = 0
for line in f:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            total += int(i)
            number_of_ints +=1
print (total)
print (number_of_ints)
```

The document is formated like: 215, 631, 731, 225, 315, etc in multiple lines
The problem is that it reads every number 1 by 1. So 100 becomes 1 + 0 + 0.
I think I need to use split to make it work but I cant figure out how to.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the document are reading looks like?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your text file so we can copy-paste and run tests on it

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each line in a file.
And you can split each line by a ',' and add each number

```
with open("\\Users\\saksa\\python_courses\\1DV501\\assign3\\file_10000integers_A.txt", "r") as f:
    total = 0
    number_of_ints = 0
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        for num in line.split(','):
            print(num)
            total += int(num)
            number_of_ints += 1

print(total)
print(number_of_ints)
```

You will need to add some logic to ensure the numbers are numbers

Comment: I reindented your code. It also helps the questioner if you clarify not only your code changes but why you did them. This takes a little more time but will make your answer searchable and get more upvotes

Answer (score -1):

You  should use `split()` function:

```
line = "110, 23400, 34569, 23567"
line.replace(" ", "") # Get rid of unnecessary spacebars
total = 0
number_of_ints = 0
for i in line.split(","):
    #  Here  you can do whatever you want
    try:
        i = int(i)
        total += int(i)
        number_of_ints += 1
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Does won't do what the questioner wants because it will still add the digits instead of the numbers

Comment: Have you  tried this solution?  The question was how to loop  over comma separated digits  in line, so  split function is doinng  it